# How to disable hover tooltip on tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to disable hover tooltips on tabs in Chrome?

They can get pretty annoying and distracting whenever the mouse pointer happens to be on a tab.

Comment: `Tooltips can get pretty annoying and distracting whenever the mouse pointer happens to be on a tab.`   That could be said about *all* tooltips, but they are (usually) handy enough to justify simply moving the cursor to a dead-spot. Maybe a program or script to automatically do that? Hmm…

Comment: Hover cards can no longer be removed. Here's the issue tracker where they're taking feedback: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot disable these tooltips in Chrome.

Via:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ygoNhTB5K1Y
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/gxAnZM-2tpM
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1562905

Comment: Please see answer below for a 2019 fix. scroll down a bit or click this link https://superuser.com/a/1495471/428827

Comment: @Sharky, yes it helped my wife, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

2019 anybody? (Works on both Chrome and Chromium btw)

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. Search for "Hover"
3. Set "Tab Hover Cards" to "Disabled"
4. Restart Chrome

[image]

Comment: I did that, but still the tooltip shows, albeit with a shorter message.

Comment: much better experience, back to what it was before i updated to the latest. the new hover was this gigantic thing, now we're back to just a single line hover tooltip. way less annoying.

Comment: This is the correct answer as of autumn 2019.

Comment: Only effective for Chrome v78-91

Answer (score 4):

I couldn’t get the [idea of a program moving the cursor](https://superuser.com/questions/655149/how-to-disable-hover-tooltip-on-tabs#comment825599_655149) for you out of my mind, so I threw one together.

Below is an AutoHotkey script (which can be compiled to a standalone executable if desired) that detects when the mouse cursor has remained idle near the top of a Chrome window for a while and if so, moves it to the lower-right corner of the screen.

It works as expected and prevents tooltips from popping up, but because of the staggered timing (the subroutine triggering and the tooltip countdown), sometimes the tooltip pops up for a split second before the cursor is moved. This can be reduced by decreasing the timer (the `tip` variable).

I’m also thinking about enhancing the script by handling the timer manually instead of using AutoHotkey’s timer. That way, it can count down from the last time that the mouse was moved or button pressed instead of just every *x* seconds regardless.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;   MoveIdleMouse.ahk
;
; Prevents tooltips from being annoying in Chrome by detecting
; when the mouse is idle while near the top of a Chrome window
; and then moving it to the bottom-right corner of the screen.
;
; https://superuser.com/questions/393738/
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

; Read the tooltip delay from the registry (this is the amount of time the
; cursor has to hover over something in order to trigger the tooltip)
RegRead, tip, HKCU, Control Panel\Mouse, MouseHoverTime

; Divide it by two to accommodate staggared timing. Adjust as desired.
;tip:=tip/2

; Set specified subroutine to run every so often (before tooltip triggered)
SetTimer, CheckCursor, %tip%

; Get the current mouse cursor position to compare to during first interval
MouseGetPos, x1, y1
return

; This subroutine checks the current cursor position and moves if idle
CheckCursor:
  ; First check if the cursor is over a Chrome window; ignore if not
  IfWinNotActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
    return

  ; Next, check if any buttons are pressed and ignore if so
  if (GetKeyState("LButton") or GetKeyState("RButton") or GetKeyState("MButton")
      or GetKeyState("XButton1") or GetKeyState("XButton2"))
    return

  ; Get the current mouse position and check if it is both unchanged, and
  ; near the top of Chrome (position is relative to window by default)
  MouseGetPos, x2, y2
  If (((x1 = x2) and (y1 = y2))  and  ((y2 >= 0) and (y2 <= 27)))
  {
    ; Move the cursor to the bottom-right corner of the screen immediately
    ; You can adjust destination position as desired
    MouseMove, A_ScreenWidth+3, A_ScreenHeight+3, 0
  }
  else {
    ; Update current cursor position to compare to during the next interval
    x1 := x2
    y1 := y2
  }
  return
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice or accept it but I 'm running Ubuntu. My bad, should've mentioned it.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately there is currently [no AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/87234-autohotkey-for-linux/) [for Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766596), but [IronAHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/50354-ironahk-alpha-cross-platform-net-rewrite-of-autohotkey/) is supposed to be portable, so that might be worth a shot. Also, there are other scripting/automation tools for Linux, so maybe the script could be ported to one of those.