# Disable Tab Hover Card in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How to disable tab hover cards, that appear when the cursor is hovered over a tab?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to disable Google Chrome tab preview on hover?](https://superuser.com/q/1499263), [How to disable hover tooltip on tabs](https://superuser.com/q/655149)

Comment: They've removed the ability to disable them again. If that bothers you, be sure to voice your opinion over on https://bugs.chromium.org/

Comment: Here's the active issue tracker for it where they're taking feedback: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215597

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE: Starting in Google Chrome v91, you can no longer disable tab hover cards. The #tab-hover-cards flag has been removed, and you can only only modify #tab-hover-card-images. A demonstration of tab hover card images can be seen on [dev.to](https://dev.to/dimshik100/chrome-tab-hover-card-images-1gch)**

**Thank you George Chakhidze for the update.**

This is a new feature in Chrome v78.

To disable tab hover cards, navigate to `chrome://flags/` in the address bar.

Then find/search for `tab hover cards` and set it to disabled.

Relaunch Chrome to apply the change.

[image]

Comment: It’s worth noting that Tab Hover Cards has “Enabled,” “Enabled B,” and “Enabled C” options—I couldn’t find a discernible difference between the three, so go with the "Disabled" option or the main “Enabled” option to revert it back.

Comment: You could also link directly to the specific setting: chrome://flags/#tab-hover-cards

Comment: In Chrome 91, the Tab Hover Cards can no longer be disabled; the setting has been removed from flags.

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze thanks I added an update.

Comment: I wonder why they removed the flag. I find the hover cards very annoying.

Comment: They sure are not only annoying, but completely ignore the selected theme. Why this is a default is beyond science.

Comment: Basically in v91 it is not possible to disable annoying ballon tips.

Comment: I see the flag is still present in Chrome 93 [chrome://flags/#tab-hover-card-images](chrome://flags/#tab-hover-card-images) but it is not disabled after disable it. That's very irritating.

Comment: @TheMechanic it looks like the feature was intended for users that browse with a lot of tabs open (I don't do this, but I know people that do). For people that do this the tab bar pretty much becomes a (bad) bookmarks menu. I guess from Google's perspective hover cards are better than nothing, because otherwise users couldn't even see the title text of the page of a tab. However, I think it's just a UX punt on the issue, the root cause is some users are really disorganized, and they're going to lose these pages they want to keep track of eventually. Nobody wants to sift through 100 tabs.

Comment: I'd say that a very easy "fix" would be to just use hover cards when there's at least N tabs open. I can't think of a use case where you'd want them when you can easily read the title of the page. I never let my tabs get so small that I can't read titles.

Comment: @jc00ke the flag `tab-hover-card-images` is still present. That will give an image along with the tab hover card. The flag to disable hover cards in general, `tab-hover-cards` is gone.

Comment: I met enough options that I couldn't change in Chrome and switched to Edge instead. Now I'm using vertical tabs and they're much better imo. More browsers should have this option.

Comment: @DrZoo ah, I clearly mixed those up. Thanks! I should ditch Chrome fully again anyway.

Comment: The `#tab-hover-card-images` option has been removed in v111.