# How to disable Google Chrome tab preview on hover?

Tags: google-chrome

Am running Chrome on Linux and upon hovering over a tab head, a text preview or popup appear, I would like that disabled because the rendering of it is lagging

This is what I mean

[image]

I tried searching for it in the settings and `chrome://flags` but couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant flag should be:

```
chrome://flags/#tab-hover-cards
```

> Enables a popup containing tab information to be visible when hovering over a tab. This will replace tooltips for tabs. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS

Comment: No longer works with v91.