# How to click at 2 different places simultaneously by only 1 click?

Tags: windows, mac

I have 2 browsers opened side by side, and there is a button **A** on the left browser, and button **B** on the right. Is there a way to click them both(**A** and **B** buttons) at the same time?

I'm currently on **Mac**, but also would like to know how can it be done on **Windows**.

Comment: Reminds me of the dual separated keys for nuclear warhead security... wait... are you attempting to initiate a nuclear launch sequence alone?  Hmmmm...  See how Richard Pryor did it in Superman III.

Comment: @lornix :))))))

Comment: Maybe using something like Sikuli-X, though I'm not sure that even Sikuli can do it concurrently.

Comment: @whitesiroi : If you like lornix's comment, then, hover your mouse to the left of his comment.  An up arrow will appear.  Click on it to give his comment an up-vote.  (Currently I see the comment having no up-votes on lornix's comment.)  I don't do that (in this case), particularly because I personally wasn't so impressed by the comment, but based on your subsequent comment, I suggest you do so.  If you follow the site's standard protocol, you will give that comment the available non-reputation-impacting (useless) reward.

Comment: @TOOGAM done :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the windows way , you can try to use the keyboard by pressing the tap key to point for the first place , and than put the mouse in the second place , and in the same time hit enter and the mouse left  click.

Comment: Of course, this is really a race condition.  You are just doing a human-level approximation of pressing both items at a close time.  And, if your mouse's click (which could just as easily be a left click) happens just a little bit earlier, then the "Enter" key won't affect the other window.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given might be half of a solution for you as it requires AutoHotKey (which AFAIK is Windows only):
[Can I mirror / duplicate mouse events on both halves of my screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/393738/can-i-mirror-duplicate-mouse-events-on-both-halves-of-my-screen)