# How do I control two cursors with one mouse?

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

I want to be able to use one mouse to control two cursors, where if I move the mouse the two cursors move together, but one cursor is offset a little. I also want both cursors to left click at the same time if I left-click the mouse. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you describe the use case?

Comment: I have two accounts on a MMORPG, and i'd like to play them at the same time on two different monitors.

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/393738/can-i-mirror-duplicate-mouse-events-on-both-halves-of-my-screen

Comment: @Paul I tried the script out but whenever I ran the it wouldn't click at all.